# Algorithm to unwrap recursive list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Problem

Say I have a list L of elements. Those elements can be either literals (strings) and/or lists L', L'',...  Now list L' can contain either literals and/or lists. I would like to unwrap them such that I get a list of all literal combinations.  What this combination looks like is easier to show than to explain; so I refer to the following examples.

1. A basic example:

   ```
   L = [a,[b,c],d]
   ```

   Solution:

   ```
   S = [[a,b,d],[a,c,d]]
   ```

   The solution is a combination of all elements of L. But the second element is another list, so I wish to create a combination with each element of the list separately.
2. More advanced example:

   ```
   L = [ a, [b,c], [d,[e]] ]
   ```

   Solution:

   ```
   S = [ [a,b,d], [a,c,d], [a,b,e], [a,c,e] ]
   ```

   I loop over the elements for each sublist to create a new combination. In the third element (list `[d,[e]]`), the second element is yet another list. But it only contains one element e, so when I loop over it it will simply return the one element.
3. Complex example:

   ```
   L = [ [a,b], [ [c,d], [e,[f,g]] ] ]
   ```

   Solving the subproblem, namely the big list in the second element:

   ```
   S' = [ [c,e,f], [c,e,g], [d,e,f], [d,e,g] ]
   ```

   The partially solved problem becomes:

   ```
   L' = [ [a,b], [ [c,e,f], [c,e,g], [d,e,f], [d,e,g] ] ]
   ```

   Final solution becomes:

   ```
   S = [ [a,c,e,f], [a,c,e,g], [a,d,e,f], [a,d,e,g], [b,c,e,f], [b,c,e,g], [b,d,e,f], [b,d,e,g] ]
   ```

   S' shows that the main problem I am solving can occur at a sublevel. For this I will need recursion.

## Question

I have a big hunch there must already be an existing algorithm for this kind of problem (or even a library; I'm using python 3). Can anyone point in the right direction for me?  I can't seem to figure this out myself.

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.product(*L)` for starters. While your problem definition is good, you don't seem to have made any coding effort to solve this yourself

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thank you Chris, I will try this right away.  I did not post what I tried because it became such a convoluted mess that it would only make my post more confusing.